# How do I specify a pip find-links option in a conda environment file?

Tags: pip, conda

I have a pip requirements file that includes specific cpu-only versions of torch and torchvision. I can use the following pip command to successfully install my requirements.

```bash
pip install --requirement azure-pipelines-requirements.txt --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

My requirements file looks like this

```
coverage
dataclasses
joblib
matplotlib
mypy
numpy
pandas
param
pylint
pyro-ppl==1.2.1
pyyaml
scikit-learn
scipy
seaborn
torch==1.4.0+cpu
torchvision==0.5.0+cpu 
visdom
```

This works from bash, but how do I invoke pip with the `find-links` option from inside a conda environment yaml file? My current attempt looks like this

```yaml
name: build  
dependencies:  
  - python=3.6  
  - pip  
  - pip:  
    - --requirement azure-pipelines-requirements.txt --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

But when I invoke

```bash
conda env create --file azure-pipeline-environment.yml
```

I get this error.

> Pip subprocess error:
>   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.4.0+cpu (from -r E:\Users\tim\Source\Talia\azure-pipelines-requirements.txt (line 25)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0+cpu (from -r E:\Users\tim\Source\Talia\azure-pipelines-requirements.txt (line 25))
>
> CondaEnvException: Pip failed

How do I specify the `find-links` option when invoking pip from a conda environment yaml file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This example](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/54e4a91d0da4d659a67e3097040764d3a2f6aa16/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip/environment.yml) shows how to specify options for pip

Specify the global pip option first:

```
name: build  
dependencies:  
  - python=3.6  
  - pip  
  - pip:
    - --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
    - --requirement azure-pipelines-requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer in the pip documentation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers). I can add the `find-links` option to my requirements file, so my conda environment yaml file becomes

```yaml
name: build
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pip
  - pip:
    - --requirement azure-pipelines-requirements.txt
```

and my pip requirements file becomes

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
coverage
dataclasses
joblib
matplotlib
mypy
numpy
pandas
param
pylint
pyro-ppl==1.2.1
pyyaml
scikit-learn
scipy
seaborn
torch==1.4.0+cpu
torchvision==0.5.0+cpu 
visdom
```

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds :)

Comment: Just testing yours then I'll mark it as the answer :)