# How to include a conda package dependency in a setup.py file?

Tags: python, pip, conda, setuptools, setup.py

I am working on a setup.py file for a Python package. I want to include the package "rdkit" among the "install_requires" dependencies of my package. However, that does not work, as rdkit cannot be directly pip-installed. My preferred method in this case is to use conda (https://anaconda.org/rdkit/rdkit).

Is there a way to automate the installation (or upgrade) if required of a package using conda in a setup.py file, similarly to what install_requires does for pip-installable dependencies?

Thank you very much for your help

```
setup(
...
  install_requires=[
      'numpy >= 1.8.0',
      'scipy >= 1.6.1',
      ],
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to automate the installation (or upgrade) if required of a package using conda in a setup.py file…?

Nop, no way. `setup.py` is intended for `python setup.py install` or `pip install` and it doesn't know anything about `conda`.

Perhaps it should be solved the other way — starting from `conda` that then [calls `pip install`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60410414/7976758) to install pip-installable packages.

Comment: Thank you for the info phd. Perhaps as a workaround: is there a way to specify some lines of code that should be run only once when a package is pip installed? Perhaps adding the code lines in setup.py before the call to the setup function or something of that sort?

Comment: @Vincent Not with wheels, possible with sdist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902139/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+post-install+script